# How to resolve "premature end of script headers" error with QGIS Server?

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-server

I attempted installing QGIS Server following [these instructions](http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/).

Installation was successful with no errors reported.

However, when I try to use `GetCapabilities` I am getting this error:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, `admin@local.domain` and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log

I looked for the error in Apache's logs and found this entry:

`[Mon Oct 28 16:02:40 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe`

Can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I get the samer error when setting `SetHandler cgi-script`
in httpd_qgis.conf When i change it to `SetHandler fcgid-script`, getCapabilities works. But then, I get the same error when executing a getMap query. BTW, I had to maually download mod_fcgis and copy it to apache/modules. Since 2.3.7 was no longer available, I had to use 2.3.9. Could that cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by manually installing the fcgi package in OSGeo4W.

according to this ticket:

http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/395

the package should now be selected as dependency by default.